# Optimization Rectangle's range of values

Tags: calculus

I have to find the deminsions of a rectangle who's perimeter is 112. I need help find the range of values of optimization.

So far I have: 
$P = 112$

$A = xy$

$P = 2x + 2y$

$112 = 2x + 2y$

$56 = x + y$

$y = 56-x$

$A = x(56-x)$
  $= -x^2 + 56x$

I'm supposed to have a range inequality which is 0 < x < "some number" How do i  find that number?

Comment: I suppose that $x>0$, $y>0$, $A>0$

Answer (score 0):

you know $A > 0$
$$
A = -x^2 + 56 x > 0
$$
$$
A = -x(x-56) > 0
$$
$$
A = x(x-56) < 0
$$
So: $ 0 < x < 56 $

Comment: That question was really bad formulated. Why couldn't he simply stated something like: Let $x,y$ be sides of a rectangle and its permiter $P=122$ find the largest value $x$ can take. If you formulate the question like this then there's no need to use the area $A$ one can simply say make $y$ as small as you want $122 > 2x$ then $0<x<56$. The optimization part in the question is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You know that $A \gt 0$, so in your last line both factors need to be positive.  That gives the upper limit for $x$